# Find Numeric Values among string from Array of Objects and do calculation

Tags: javascript, reactjs

My JavaScript array looks like this.

```
[ 
{id:1, msg:"Your Acct 123XXXX456 Has Been Debited with USD2,100.00 On 05- 
MAY- 2019 07:26:58 By AB: 123456**7899/USER NAME/0505201. Bal: 
USD973.28CR"}, <br/>
{id:1, msg: "Your Acct 123XXXX456 Has Been Debited with USD1,100.00 On 
05-MAY-2019 07:26:58 By AB: 123456**7899/USER NAME/0505201. Bal: 
USD673.28CR"},<br/>
{id:2, msg: "Your Acct 345XXXX678 Has Been Debited with USD4,100.00 On 
05-MAY-2019 07:26:58 By AB: 11111**22222/USER NAME/0505201. Bal: 
USD373.28CR"}
]
```

I need to pick the following details:

```
(1) Highest Debit amount (for particular user)
(2) Lowest Debit amount (for particular user)
(3) Sum all the debit amount for particular user.
```

I tried the following approach to get the non-digits from string.

```
let result = myArr[0].replace(/\D+/g, ' ').trim().split(' ').map(e => 
parseInt(e));
```

But output was like this.

```
[123,456,2,1,00,5]
```

This approach is putting comma in front of each digit, removing decimal point with preceding 00. I don't have any idea how to pick only debit amount.
I am expecting output like this:

```
User   Highest Debit    Lowest Debit   Total Debit 
 1       2,100.00         1,100.00       3,200.00 
 2       4,100.00         4,100.00       4,100.00
```

```js
myArr = [{
    "id": 1,
    "msg": "Your Acct 123XXXX456 Has Been Debited with USD2,100.00 On 05- MAY - 2019 07: 26: 58 By AB: 123456 ** 7899 / USER NAME / 0505201. Bal: USD973 .28 CR "
  },
  {
    "id": 1,
    "msg": "Your Acct 123XXXX456 Has Been Debited with USD1,100.00 On 05 - MAY - 2019 07: 26: 58 By AB: 123456 ** 7899 / USER NAME / 0505201. Bal: USD673 .28 CR "
  },
  {
    "id": 2,
    "msg": "Your Acct 345XXXX678 Has Been Debited with USD4,100.00 On 05 - MAY - 2019 07: 26: 58 By AB: 11111 ** 22222 / USER NAME / 0505201. Bal: USD373 .28 CR "
  }
]

let result = myArr[0].replace(/\D+/g, ' ').trim().split(' ').map(e =>
  parseInt(e));
console.log(result)
```

Comment: I made you a snippet. `myArr[0]` is an object. You need to use `myArr[0].msg.replace`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your regex is too simple

Here is one way to get at each debit using Math.min and Math.max

I was considering using reduce but this is more readable

```js
myArr = [
  { "id": 1, "msg": "Your Acct 123XXXX456 Has Been Debited with USD2,100.45 On 05 - MAY - 2019 07: 26: 58 By AB: 123456 ** 7899 / USER NAME / 0505201. Bal: USD973 .28 CR " },
  { "id": 1, "msg": "Your Acct 123XXXX456 Has Been Debited with USD1,100.50 On 05 - MAY - 2019 07: 26: 58 By AB: 123456 ** 7899 / USER NAME / 0505201. Bal: USD673 .28 CR " },
  { "id": 2, "msg": "Your Acct 345XXXX678 Has Been Debited with USD4,100.00 On 05 - MAY - 2019 07: 26: 58 By AB: 11111 ** 22222 / USER NAME / 0505201. Bal: USD373 .28 CR "}
]

let res = {}
myArr.forEach(obj => {
    const id  = obj.id;
    const msg = obj.msg;
    const uPos = msg.indexOf("USD"); // assuming a static message
    // grab the amount, use + to convert to number after removing the thousand separator
    const num = +msg.substring(uPos+3,msg.indexOf(" ",uPos)).replace(/,/g,"")
    let cur = res[id];
    if (!cur) { res[id]={}; cur=res[id]; cur.total=0;}
    cur.low  =  cur.low  ?  Math.min(cur.low, num) : num;
    cur.high =  cur.high ?  Math.max(cur.high,num) : num;
    cur.total += num;
})
console.log(res);
```

Comment: Thanks for your help. Will this also support decimal point? like if debit amount is 2100.50

Comment: Yes it already does. See update. The `+` converts to number and drops .00 in the process but not .05 for example

Comment: Nice. Thanks a lot for your time and help.